# Object Bounding Box Detection Algorithm Complexity OpenCV

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, time-complexity

What are the computational complexity of algorithms for following tasks in OpenCV :

- Object Tracking in Video Frames
- Bounding Box of object detection in Video Frames

I am interested in knowing computational complexity in terms of following frame resolution, number of objects etc.

Comment: Completely depends on which algorithms you're using specifically. For most of these algorithms, references are given in the documentation to the original papers which you can peruse.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Agreed. I want to compare processing time of standard Image Processing algorithms with that of Deep Learning models, like YOLO, R-CNN etc. Can you point me to any doc which compares them ?

Comment: check this out https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/object-detection-speed-and-accuracy-comparison-faster-r-cnn-r-fcn-ssd-and-yolo-5425656ae359